# what 5-letter word is the antonym of "stink"?

Tags: antonyms, questions

It's really really hard to guess the word. All I know is "fragrance" , ""sweetness", etc.
please help me with this stuff :)

Comment: You seem to consider that there is such a word. May we know the reason for your confidence? We don't contribute here to homework appeals. And this bears the aroma of such a request.

Comment: Any letters you know, third letter an 'e'?

Comment: Which crossword puzzle are you working on?  Try oneacross.com

Comment: If you're looking for a five-letter word that is "stink" spelled backwards, I have the answer!

Answer (score 1):

[aroma](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aroma): an odor arising from spices, plants, cooking, etc., especially **an agreeable odor**; a distinctive **usually pleasant** smell, esp of spices, wines, and plants.

Try Powerthesaurus.org for antonyms and synonyms, esp. for crossword puzzles (it's very good). There's always OneAcross.com.

Comment: Yeah, this for odor sounds most favorable.  I remember it the most from a coffee commercial when I was a child in the early 1980's.

Answer (score 1):

**scent**

> **1** A distinctive smell, especially one that is pleasant:
>   *the scent of freshly cut hay*
>
> **1.1** [mass noun] Pleasant-smelling liquid worn on the skin; perfume:
>   *she sprayed scent over her body*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scent)

Comment: "How to Remove a Skunk Scent" is a fairly common search. And a rich source of answers to that all-too-common dilemma (I have dogs, and thrice is all-too-common for *that* dilemma.) Perhaps relatively common only because it's well known that their distinctive aroma comes from *scent* glands.

Comment: Fortunately, skunks are not particularly common in the UK.

Comment: I'm envious. It's a powerful olfactory experience, actually making all involved cry (except the skunk, of course.) The whole affair is very impressive.

Comment: Except when one of the involved parties is a car, in which case even the skunk is not happy.

Answer (score -1):

the good answer is odour.............................................................................................................................

Comment: Why would that be the opposite from stink?  If anything its a synonym.

Comment: @DavidM: Hey, lets not forget: its always good to include an apostrophe in ones contractions!

Comment: @rhetorician Yes.  And, my stupid autocorrect seems to be at war with them!  It's and its makes the darned thing go haywire.  So, I type it correctly, and it "fixes" it for me without my noticing!

Comment: @DavidM: Yeah, I feel you (as the young people say nowadays). It's like a would-be grammarian who corrects a person by saying "No, it's 'my wife and I,'" when the person says, "The plan works well for my wife and me"! As for MY autocorrect, it wants to capitalize every first word in, say, a single-spaced block quotation. Very irritating.